# Microsoft Dynamics CRM online supports only reports that use Fetch XML data sources

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012

I have created a report with Visual Studio 2010 and when I load it to CRM Online, I get this error:

> Error : Invalid Data Source : This report type is not supported.
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM online supports only reports that use Fetch XML
>   data sources.

This the query I am using:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="lead">
    <attribute name="fullname" />
    <attribute name="companyname" />
    <attribute name="telephone1" />
    <attribute name="leadid" />
    <order attribute="fullname" descending="false" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Do you have please any idea about the source of this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

FetchXML is correct works for me properly review the technet have if you can help https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328437.aspx